# Initialize javascript functions array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to programmatically create a Javascript functions array from an array of strings.

For example if my array is this:

```
myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I need to create something like this:

```
myFunctArray = [
    function(d) {
        return d['a'];
    },
    function(d) {
        return d['b'];
    },
    function(d) {
        return d['c'];
    },
    function(d) {
        return d['d'];
    }
]
```

Now I need to be able to do this programmatically for any array so I tried this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
    myFunctArray.push(function(d){            
        return d[myArray[i]];
    });
}
```

What I get is an array with functions all identical to the last one. I think there's an issue of scope, but I cannot find a solution. I tried a lot of different variants with no luck and Google didn't help.
Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a scope problem related to use `i` inside a function without "freezeing" the value. You could solve it with this [`closure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

```
for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
    function(index) {
        myFunctArray.push(function(d){            
            return d[myArray[index]];
        });
    }(i); // call immediately inline defined function
}
```

Comment: Small typo: "immediately" not "inmediatly"

Comment: Grazie Claudio, I just copied/pasted but I get a JS error saying that the '(' at this line  function(index) { is unexpected...